# Iterating through URLs

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a website by iterating through the URL and appending the collected data into a list. I know its not pretty (very new), but I am fairly happy with everything up until the iteration:

```
for date in date_list: # iterate through dates
        weather_list = pd.read_html(base_url + 'KOWD' + '/' + year + '/' + month + '/' + day + end_url)
```

I know in the for statement, I have to call year, month, day, in order to iterate through them - but I thought by declaring them in the dataframe, they will be recognized as the list. Does anyone have any advice? Can't get passed this!

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from datetime import datetime

base_url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/'
end_url = '/DailyHistory.html?req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo='

start_date = '1970, 1, 1'
end_date = '1970, 1, 3'

daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)

date_list = []
for single_date in daterange: # create list of dates
    date_list.append(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

date_list = pd.DataFrame(date_list, columns = ['date'])

date_list['year'], date_list['month'], date_list['day'] = zip(*date_list['date'].map(lambda x: x.split('-'))) # split date into parts
year = date_list['year']
month = date_list['month']
day = date_list['day']
#print(year)
#print(month)
#print(day)
#print(type(date_list))        
#print(date_list)

for date in date_list: # iterate through dates
    weather_list = pd.read_html(base_url + 'KOWD' + '/' + year + '/' + month + '/' + day + end_url)
    #print(type(weather_list))
    weather_list = weather_list[4] # this is the table of values I want
    weather_list.append(date)
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I didn't even ask a question, nice... Ha. I want to know how I can pass the three values (year, month, day) into my for loop to collect and append data at each new URL. The way I'm showing it above gives me an error 'TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'Series'. But I suspect something else is done wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier just to iterate through the dates in `daterange`:

```
daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
url_template = base_url + 'KOWD/{d.year}/{d.month}/{d.day}' + end_url
for date in daterange:
    url = url_template.format(d=date)
    weather_list = pd.read_html(url)
    # etc.
```

If this works for you then you can drop all the subsequent code that stores the dates in a dataframe, changes them into strings, and creates separate columns for year, month and date.

If you do need to create a dataframe of the dates you could do this:

```
date_list = pd.DataFrame(daterange, columns=['date'])
for k in ['year', 'month', 'day']:
    date_list[k] = date_list.apply(lambda r: getattr(r.date, k), axis=1)
```

You can then iterate throw the rows.

```
for index, row in date_list.iterrows():
    url = url_template.format(d=row)
    weather_list = pd.read_html(url)
    # etc.
```

Then consider what format you want the `weather_list` output to be in. If the information scraped is not suitable to be included in the data frame then it might make more sense as a dictionary of `{date: table}` pairs.

Edit: For example if you want to pick the 3rd table from each page and concatenate it together with the date into a single dataframe, you could do this:

```
weather_dict = {}
for date in daterange:
    table = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[2]
    table.set_index(table.columns.values[0], inplace=True)
    table.index.set_names(None, inplace=True)
    weather_dict[date] = table

weather_df = pd.concat(weather_dict)
```

Comment: Great thanks Stuart! The first method worked, so now just cleaning up the data a bit for usage. Just so I'm understanding the data types: `weather_list = pd.read_html(url, header = 0)
    weather_list = weather_list[4]` - the pd.read_html returns an indexed list of the available lists at the URL, and weather_list[4] gets the index 4 table and puts it to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: `pd.read_html` returns a list of dataframes based on the tables found in the page, and `weather_list[4]` would be the 5th of these dataframes. (But as noted in the other post there are only 4 tables on this page.)

Answer (score 1):

Variables `year`, `month` and `day` are of type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. You need to access them as you loop through them. Consider below code.

```
for i in range(0,len(date_list)): # iterate through dates
    weather_list = pd.read_html(base_url + 'KOWD' + '/' + year[i] + '/' + month[i] + '/' + day[i] + end_url)
    #print(type(weather_list))
    weather_list = weather_list[4] # this is the table of values I want
    weather_list.append(date_list.iloc[i])
```

Note: Upon running this code, the `IndexError` that you mentioned was solved but I was getting error on `weather_list = weather_list[4]` line. I checked and the `len(weather_list)` is always 4. Definitely it is a separate issue as `list index out of range` is bound to happen in this case.

Comment: Harv, thanks for the response. My thinking was the `pd.read_html` returns a list and then the `weather_list = weather_list[4]` returns a dataframe of the 4th table in that list... can you clarify if this is my correct understanding? Maybe I didn't understand the documentation!

Comment: @DavidBlack, `pd.read_html()` returns a `list of DataFrames`. In yur case you have total of 4 dataframes in the list returned. If you want the 4th / last dataframe. That will be `weather_list[3]` as a list of 4 would have indices 0 to 3.